Is the time complexity of Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm polynomial?
I'm trying to use Scipy's least_squares function and the documentation says that least_squares uses the Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm.

Method ‘lm’ (Levenberg-Marquardt) calls a wrapper over least-squares algorithms implemented in MINPACK (lmder, lmdif). It runs the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm formulated as a trust-region type algorithm.

I was wondering whether the time complexity Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm is polynomial or not. If not, are there any polynomial algorithms that also solves "non-linear least square" problem, like Levenberg-Marquadt? I tried searching on Google or Stack Overflow but nothing works.

Good question! Yes, it is polynomial. O(N^3). But if the convergence would be fast, then it could be down to O(N). So, the time complexity is O(N^3). See this and this.

Also you can ask a question at CS
